# What is this terrible-looking hairy plant with maybe nice flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this terrible-looking hairy plant with maybe nice flowers?

Its height is 25cm/1ft, this is the only specimen in my yard, it could be non-invasive, but it looks no beautiful to me, so I will most likely treat it as a weed.

Sorry for blurry pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

New photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could post another picture that shows the plant in focus? Its hard to see the leaves clearly

Comment: Will do it, but can't at this moment. @Bamboo

Comment: Does it smell? I would go to some Senecio or Artemisia (and related genera)

Comment: I didn't try smelling it, but I will, even though I don't have  particularly strong urge to do it. :) @Giacomo

Comment: @Bamboo New photos of this plant.

Comment: @Giacomo New photos of this plant.

Answer (score 2):

The plant looks a lot like *Chrysocephalum apiculatum*.

I’m not certain because it’s difficult to determine the leaf shape from your photos, but the flowers and growth form match.

From Wikipedia...

> Chyrsocephalum apiculatum is known by the common names common
>   everlasting and yellow buttons. It is a perennial herb native to
>   southern Australia. It is a member of Asteraceae, the daisy family. It
>   grows in sunny locations on light, well-drained soil in grassy areas.
>   It is an important food plant for the Australian butterfly painted
>   lady (Vanessa kershawi).

Comment: New photos of this plant.